# Filling a python dictionary in for loop returns same values

Tags: python, python-2.7

For the needs of the project im iterating over some data and adding needed values to premade dictionary.

here is striped down example of code which represents my question:

```
class Parser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.records = [['value1','value2','value3'], 
                        ['value4','value5','value6'],
                        ['value7','value8','value9']]
    def get_parsed(self):
        parsed = []
        dic = {'key1': '',
               'key2': '',
               'key3': '',
               }
        for i in self.records:
            dic['key1'] = i[0]
            dic['key2'] = i[1]
            dic['key3'] = i[2]
            parsed.append(dic)
        return parsed
```

What i expect to get is list of dicts like this:

```
[{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'},
 {'key1':'value4','key2':'value5','key3':'value6'},
 {'key1':'value7','key2':'value8','key3':'value9'}]
```

But what im getting is:

```
[{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'},
 {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'},
 {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}]
```

Though if i move dictionary initialization into 'for' loop - im getting the desired result  but i don't understand why is that happening?

EDIT:
The question is more "Why does it happens this way"
I did some testing in ipython and that's what i've got:

```
In [1]: d = {'a':'','b':'','c':''}

In [2]: d
Out[2]: {'a': '', 'b': '', 'c': ''}

In [3]: d['a'] = 'value'

In [4]: d['b'] = 'other_value'

In [5]: d['c'] = 'third_value'

In [6]: d
Out[6]: {'a': 'value', 'b': 'other_value', 'c': 'third_value'}

In [7]: d['a'] = 'inserting new value'

In [8]: d
Out[8]: {'a': 'inserting new value', 'b': 'other_value', 'c': 'third_value'}
```

So the value of the key could be updated and it **changes**, why doesn't it happen in FOR loop?

Comment: Aside: you don't need to write `dic = {'a': '', etc.}`.  `dic = {}` would suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `dic` is created outside the loop, you only create one dict.  If you want three different dicts, you need to create three different dicts, so move the initial creation of `dic` inside the loop.

To answer your updated question, the issue is that although you think you are appending a new dict with each `parsed.append(dic)`, you are just appending the same dict three times.  `Append` doesn't copy the dict.  So whenever you modify that dict, all the dicts in `parse` show the change, since they are all the same dict.  This version of your second code example may be more illustrative:

```
>>> d = {'a': '', 'b': '', 'c': ''}
>>> stuff = []
>>> stuff.append(d)
>>> print stuff
[{'a': '', 'c': '', 'b': ''}]
>>> d['a'] = 'other'
>>> print stuff
[{'a': 'other', 'c': '', 'b': ''}]
>>> stuff.append(d)
>>> print stuff
[{'a': 'other', 'c': '', 'b': ''}, {'a': 'other', 'c': '', 'b': ''}]
>>> d['a'] = 'yet another'
>>> print stuff
[{'a': 'yet another', 'c': '', 'b': ''}, {'a': 'yet another', 'c': '', 'b': ''}]
```

Notice that changing the dict "works" in that it indeed changes the value, but regardless of that, the list still contains the same dict multiple times, so any changes you make overwrite whatever changes you made earlier.  In the end, your list only contains the last version of the dict, because all earlier changes were overwritten in all dicts in the list.

Comment: Thanks! That totally makes sence now :)

Answer (score 5):

You are modifying and inserting *the same dictionary* to your list three times. Create a *new dictionary* for each iteration of the loop:

```
for i in self.records:
    dic = { 'key1': i[0], 'key2': i[1], 'key3': i[2] }
    parsed.append(dic)
```

Comment: Yes i found it out "the hard way" though my question is more: Isn't the dictionary values rewritten each time i write new value? Updating my question with small example now

Comment: @AkiraKir: It does change, but it changes *all* the values in the list, because they are all the same dictionary.  (There seems to be an error in your example.  If I run your code I get all dictionaries containing "value7", "value8", and "value9".)

Comment: You only create a single dictionary, then you append 3 references to that same dictionary. changing the single dictionary in the for loop.  What you want to do is create a new dictionary object in each iteration of the for loop, by moving your `dic = {...}` line inside the for loop.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Yes i misstyped, im getting the last values, not the first ones