# Iterating over List[] takes and composing a dict only uses first list element

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm using Python and Selenium to scrape data from a HTML page. I'm selecting a `<ul>` element which has several `<li>` children which contain the data I want. But when iterating over the `List[WebElement]` and composing a dict based on the `.text` value of the `<div>`s by querying the element with `.find_element_by_xpath()`, I only get the `.text` value of the first `div`.

I stripped down the python code and the  HTML code as far as I could:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="listUl">
        <li id="item1">
            <div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="titel">
                        <div class="item_titel">Hello World</div>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="key">
                        <div class="item_key">HELLO_WORLD</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="item2">
            <div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="titel">
                        <div class="item_titel">Merry Christmas</div>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="key">
                        <div class="item_key">MERRY_CHRISTMAS</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div>
        </li>                                                       
    </ul>
</body>
```

```
from typing import List
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

path: str = "file:///C:/Users/<username>/Desktop/main3.html"
list_block = "//ul[@id='listUl']"
list_elements = "//li"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(path)

def get_data(list_item: WebElement) -> dict:
    return {
        'id': list_item.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='item_key']").text,
        'titel': list_item.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='item_titel']").text
    }

block_we: WebElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath(list_block)
result: List[dict] = []
block: WebElement = block_we
li_list: List[WebElement] = block.find_elements_by_xpath(list_elements)
for item in li_list:
    result.append(get_data(item))

print(result)   #[{'id': 'HELLO_WORLD', 'titel': 'Hello World'}, {'id': 'HELLO_WORLD', 'titel': 'Hello World'}]
```

I found this SO Post: [Filling a python dictionary in for loop returns same values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753099/filling-a-python-dictionary-in-for-loop-returns-same-values)
so I thought, that maby I' missing to create a new dict, and the first entry is alway re-used. so I made a seperate variable for each entry:

```
item1 = {   # item1: {'id': 'HELLO_WORLD', 'titel': 'Hello World'}
    'id': li_list[0].find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='item_key']").text,
    'titel': li_list[0].find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='item_titel']").text
}
item1_text = li_list[0].text    #item1_text: 'Hello World\nHELLO_WORLD'
item2 = {   # item2: {'id': 'HELLO_WORLD', 'titel': 'Hello World'}
    'id': li_list[1].find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='item_key']").text,
    'titel': li_list[1].find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='item_titel']").text
}
item2_text = li_list[1].text    # item2_text: 'Merry Christmas\nMERRY_CHRISTMAS
```

Can someone tell me which mistake I make?

EDIT: To make sure, that the Xpath is not wrong, I changed the relative `//div[@class='item_key']` and `//div[@class='item_titel']` to the absolut value `//div/div/div[1]/div` and `//div/div/div[2]/div` and added an html property to the result of `get_data`:

```
def get_data(list_item: WebElement) -> dict:
return {
    'id': list_item.find_element_by_xpath("//div/div/div[1]/div").text,
    # 'id': list_item.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='item_key']").text,
    'titel': list_item.find_element_by_xpath("//div/div/div[2]/div").text,
    # 'titel': list_item.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='item_titel']").text,
    'text': list_item.text,
    'html': list_item.get_attribute("innerHTML").replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '')
}
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        'id': 'Hello World', 
        'titel': 'HELLO_WORLD', 
        'text': 'Hello World\nHELLO_WORLD', 
        'html': '<div><div class="content"><div class="titel"><div class="item_titel">Hello World</div></div><div class="key"><div class="item_key">HELLO_WORLD</div></div></div></div>'
    }, 
    {
        'id': 'Hello World', 
        'titel': 'HELLO_WORLD', 
        'text': 'Merry Christmas\nMERRY_CHRISTMAS', 'html': '<div><div class="content"><div class="titel"><div class="item_titel">Merry Christmas</div></div><div class="key"><div class="item_key">MERRY_CHRISTMAS</div></div></div></div>'
    }
]
```

But still, if more than 1 `<li>` element is in my `List[WebElements]`, querying via `.find_element_by_xpath("//div/div/div[1]/div")` and `.find_element_by_xpath("//div/div/div[2]/div")` returns only for element 0. Even if I call my get_data function with `block.find_elements_by_xpath(list_elements)[0]` or `block.find_elements_by_xpath(list_elements)[1]` or just with index 1,  `.find_element_by_xpath()` with the absolut oder relative xpath just returns values for the first element.

When altering the HTML file so that only the second `<li>` remains inside the file, the `.find_element_by_xpath()` function returns the titel and key for the (previously) second, now first element. When putting the (previously) first element after the second element (switching) both elements, the result of get_data is now flipped (`id` and `titel` show element #1 and ony #1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

Problem was that I forgot to add a `.` to the XPath query in the `get_data()` function.
This SO post describes the same problem: [Iterating through elements get repeating result on Selenium on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162795/iterating-through-elements-get-repeating-result-on-selenium-on-python)

If I dont't add a `.`, the XPath will search from the top of the DOM and return always the same item.

Thank you!